# freepbx. Significant call time with BUSY status

Tags: freepbx, cdr

I got big bill from operator.The duration of calls there significantly exceeds the sum in the sample from the asterisk database with the ANSWERED status

```
2021-11-09 20:16:33 XXXXXXXXX   3333    SIP/vodaphone-0000fad6  899 BUSY
2021-11-09 20:31:32 XXXXXXXXX   3333    SIP/vodaphone-0000fad6  0   BUSY
2021-11-09 20:31:32 XXXXXXXXX   3333    SIP/vodaphone-0000fad6  15  NO ANSWER
2021-11-09 20:31:32 XXXXXXXXX   3333    SIP/vodaphone-0000fad6  15  NO ANSWER
2021-11-09 20:32:07 XXXXXXXXX   3333    SIP/vodaphone-0000fad6  0   BUSY
2021-11-09 20:32:07 XXXXXXXXX   3333    SIP/vodaphone-0000fad6  0   BUSY
2021-11-09 20:32:07 XXXXXXXXX   3333    SIP/vodaphone-0000fad6  1   NO ANSWER
2021-11-09 20:32:07 XXXXXXXXX   3333    SIP/vodaphone-0000fad6  106 ANSWERED
```

The situation as it appeared itself and passed by itself.
On the detail from the operator, the duration of the call is equal to the sum of the durations of all records. There is no robot or IVR there. 
The handset, as I understand it, did not rise and the call was not placed on hold. Can someone suggest how to appeal to an operator with such a problem?
FreePBX 15.0.17.24
Asterisk 16.6.2,

Answer (score -1):

This issue was caused by Queue no answer off  setting. Asterisk accept call but there are no free agent so operator start count time without real conversation.